# HTML+CSS Hover sprites, different size icons, one background-position CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, position, sprite

Bear with me on this one, it's hard to explain:

I have 4 **-DIFFERENT SIZE-** icons: [image]  [image]  [image]  [image] and another 4 for the hover effect: [image]  [image]  [image]  [image]

After countless failed attempts, I decided to ask:

How do I create 4 seperate sprite files (1 file = normal + hover version of the icon) in such a way/format that I could use the same CSS class (with the same `background-position`) and just change the `background-image` using inline-css on the  element (See HTML code below ) while keeping the positioning?

For example:
 `background-position: 0 0;` for the normal look, and then on the `a:hover` - `background-position: 0 -45;` for every single icon pair.

I tried using various generators but what I get is like `0 -45` for one sprite and `0 -37` for another one etc.

Maybe someone could actually generate it the 'right way'?

HTML:

```
<div class="menuPicHeader"> 
     <a href="#" style="background-image: url(sprite1.png);" class="">Text1</a>
     <a href="#" style="background-image: url(sprite2.png);" class="">Text2</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuPicHeader a{   
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 0 0 0 45px;
        height: 50px;
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

.menuPicHeader a:hover{
        background-position: ? ?;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, after a LOT of trial and error. Basically, I put the top icon 2 vertical pixels off of the top of png, and use `background-position: 0 -2px` on the normal state. Then, put the hover version for example 50 pixels below, with 2 pixels already inside the second picture (so basically 48px), and then use `background-position: 0 -50px` on the `a:hover`